# Javascript object not displaying text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript after learning programming in Java, so I tried to define a simple object in Javascript in an HTML page, but the code won't show me the results of calculations (IE not diplaying areas, perimeters nor which rectangle is bigger). There seems to be no grammar error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
  <script language ="JavaScript">

          Rectangle = function(b,h) {

                     this.base = parseInt(b);
                     this.height = parseInt(h);

                     this.area = b*h;
                     this.perimeter = (b+h)*2;
                     this.diagonal = sqrt(b*b+h*h);

                     }

            </script>

    </head>

    <body>

          <h3>Rectangles!</h3>
          <b>First rectangle</b><br><br>
          Base: <input type = "number" id = "base1" value = "0">
          Height: <input type = "number" id = "height1" value = "0">
          <br><br>
          <b>Second rectangle</b><br><br>
          Base: <input type = "number" id = "base2" value = "0">
          Altezza: <input type = "number" id = "height2" value = "0">

          <br><br><br>
          <b>Data about first rectangle:</b><br><br>
          <t>Perimeter is <div id = "p1"> </div>
          <t>Area is <div id = "a1"> </div>
          <t>Diagonal is <div id = "d1"> </div>
          <br><br>
          <b>Data about second rectangle:</b><br><br>
          <t>Perimeter is <div id = "p2"> </div>
          <t>Area is <div id = "a2"> </div>
          <t>Diagonal is <div id = "d2"> </div>
          <br><br>
          <div id = "compare"> </div>

          <script language = "JavaScript">
                  A = new Rectangle(document.getElementById("base1").value,document.geteElementById("altezza1"));
                  B = new Rectangle(document.getElementById("base2").value,document.geteElementById("altezza2"));
                  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = A.perimeter;
                  document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = A.area;
                  document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = A.diagonal;
                  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = B.perimeter;
                  document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML = B.area;
                  document.getElementById("d2").innerHTML = B.diagonal;
                  if A.area > B.area document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "First rectangle is bigger";
                  if A.area < B.area document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "Second rectangle is bigger";
                  else               document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "Rectangles are equal";
                  </script>

         </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code. Better checking the console for errors. The if/else constructs are wrong also `geteElementById` which is called `getElementById`.

Comment: You don't seem to have an element(s) with the ids of `altezza1` and 2

Comment: Missing parentheses around the if conditions. You definitely have syntax errors in your console

Comment: Looks like you are not using any browser debugging tools. See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Downvoted for not checking the console for obvious errors before posting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change

```
this.diagonal = sqrt(b*b+h*h);
```

to

```
this.diagonal = Math.sqrt(b*b+h*h);
```

Secondly

```
geteElementById
```

to (too much "e")

```
getElementById
```

And ifs are wrong. Instead of

```
if A.area > B.area document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "First rectangle is bigger";
                  if A.area < B.area document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "Second rectangle is bigger";
                  else               document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "Rectangles are equal";
```

write something like this

```
document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = (A.area > B.area) ? "First rectangle is bigger" : ((A.area < B.area) ? "Second rectangle is bigger" : "Rectangles are equal")
```

Also - You execute script just one even before fields are filled.
Do it on click / submit / value change.

And as guys above stated - use browser debugging tools.
"Console" tab in those tools tells you everything you need to know about your errors.

Answer (score 0):

There was many typos and wrong syntax in your code, try this:

```
function Rectangle(b,h) {

                     this.base = parseInt(b);
                     this.height = parseInt(h);

                     this.area = b*h;
                     this.perimeter = (b+h)*2;
                     this.diagonal = Math.sqrt(b*b+h*h);
console.log(this.perimeter);
                     }

          console.log(document.getElementById("base1").value);

 var A = new Rectangle(document.getElementById("base1").value,document.getElementById("height1").value);
 var B = new Rectangle(document.getElementById("base2").value,document.getElementById("height2").value);            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = A.perimeter;
        document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = A.area;
                  document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = A.diagonal;
                  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = B.perimeter;
                  document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML = B.area;
                  document.getElementById("d2").innerHTML = B.diagonal;           
 if (A.area > B.area) document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "First rectangle is bigger";
 if (A.area < B.area) document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "Second rectangle is bigger";
  else               document.getElementById("compare").innerHTML = "Rectangles are equal";
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. And I swear I checked the console, I must have done some errors while translating into English because I wrote it in another language first

Comment: (it gives NaN as a result)

Comment: NaN -> Not a Number, so you can check on your input you are passing to Rectangel function, var A = new Rectangle(document.getElementById("base1").value,document.getElementById("height1").value);
 var B = new Rectangle(document.getElementById("base2").value,document.getElementById("height2").value); . Please check whether your are providing correct values